# How to make a "recent seen pages" for user registered in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is there a plugin that returns to a wordpress registered user the last pages that he has seen on a blog?

Thanks in advance, Joe

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for it, but I found [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/last-viewed-posts/) over at wordpress.org.